# Android security: how secure is the app private data?

Tags: android, security, appdata

I have an application that stores confidential information in a file located in the application's private data folder.

I would like to know how secure it is to do so.

As far as I know on an android device other applications cannot access that file.

Supposing:

- the device is not rooted
- there is a password protection on the lock screen
- a hacker has stolen that device and he is really forced to get that file

What kind of tricks are there to get that file somehow? I mean:

- Is it possible to get the device rooted (in this scenario) and then get that file?
- Can the hacker physically take out the flash chip from the device and then he analyzes it using any tool. Does Android make any encryption preventing this way to happen?
- Other ways to get that file maybe?

Is it possible at all to fully protect that file somehow? 
Maybe the application could have an autostart service that monitors the rooted status. If the device gets rooted the service deletes the file immediately.

Thank you!

Comment: Most Android devices now come with an option to encrypt the data on the phone, in the Settings menu.  You can always encrypt the file yourself before saving it to disk.
Also, if the phone is rooted, there is nothing stopping the root user from gaining access to any file they want.

Comment: How about encrypting the file when it is written? :)

Comment: new versions of android (5.0) can encrypt the file system if user applys that. for the rest of the things, once one smart guy has physical access to a machine, you can consider everything can be lost: You cannot prevent the system root or whatever...

Comment: My application needs to read and write that file, so encryption is useless from a hacker point of view. If my app can read and write the file then a hacker "easily" can find the appropriate code in the app and use that to reveal the content of the file.

Comment: If you ask this question at [XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/), you'll probably get a better answer. In a nutshell: 1) A device can be rooted (90% of Android devices are rootable), 2) Your device can be mounted with a special tool which can pull the entire ROM (i.e. Android firmware) off your device, 3) ROM can then be browsed like a normal archive listing your system and any other directories or information within the pulled ROM, 4) APKs in the ROM can be disassembled using special tools - one just need to know how to read `baksmali` - low level language, like `Assembly`.

Comment: You can safeguard your data on the local device by using an AES crypto encryption module, like BouncyCastle for example. Most modern relational database management system (RDBMS) provides methods to AES-encrypt and decrypt data, so you could decrypt the data from your database, sent it to your device to do some work, encrypt your data again via your app using an AES crypto module and sent it back to your database. Of course, you may want to employ a secured communication channel between your database and your device using a protocol like HTTPS, SFTP, etc, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the device rooted (in this scenario) and then get that file?

Yes, assuming:

- the hacker can brute-force the password, and
- the device is rootable in general (not every device has a known recipe for gaining root)

> Can the hacker physically take out the flash chip from the device and then he analyzes it using any tool.

In theory, though that would not be easy to do without physically damaging it.

> Does Android make any encryption preventing this way to happen?

Android offers full-disk encryption, and it is enabled by default on new Android 5.0 devices. Older Android devices' full-disk encryption could be brute-forced; Android 5.0's seems stronger in this regard, though only time will tell if it too has flaws.

> Is it possible at all to fully protect that file somehow?

Do not put the file on the device in the first place.

Or, encrypt it yourself, with a passphrase known to the user that is sufficiently strong. You eventually get to a point where [a $5 wrench](http://xkcd.com/538/) is a more viable approach than is trying to hack the device.

> Maybe the application could have an autostart service that monitors the rooted status. If the device gets rooted the service deletes the file immediately.

Your application is not running in some of these circumstances, in part because the OS is not necessarily running in normal mode.

Furthermore, even if your application is running, the attacker will simply force-stop it from Settings after getting past the lockscreen and before attempting to set up root access.

And, this assumes that your app knows all possible ways of detecting root access, which seems unlikely.

> My application needs to read and write that file, so encryption is useless from a hacker point of view

Only if your application needs to "read and write that file" without the user supplying the passphrase. In this scenario, your only absolute defense is to not have the file. Everything else just slows attacks down but cannot stop them.

Comment: Is it possible to root the device without knowing the lock screen password? I'm asking this because if the user is using a 6 character password [a-z], then the brute force must make at most 26^6 attempts. After each 5 attempts it have to wait for 30 seconds (because of Android) this means 58 years to try each combinations. For me it sounds good. So if the device is non-rooted and it has at least 6 character long lock screen password and the file system is encrypted then I think it is secure enough. What do you think?

Comment: @Zsolt: "Is it possible to root the device without knowing the lock screen password?" -- I can't rule it out but on Android 4.2+ devices my guess is that you need to have the device unlocked. "After each 5 attempts it have to wait for 30 seconds (because of Android) this means 58 years to try each combinations" -- you assume that this is the best way to do the brute-forcing. "What do you think?" -- I think that I have no idea what you are trying to defend, and any intelligent discussion of security measures starts there. What is reasonable for state secrets is not reasonable for selfies.

Comment: Do you know any other ways for brute force? If the device is not rooted then you cannot access the password.key file to speed up the process, so you have to use some USB keyboard emulation solution to do this automatically. If this is true, then I think it is secure enough. But I have not heard any other ways to do this. That is why I am asking you guys.

Comment: @Zsolt: "Do you know any other ways for brute force?" -- yes. A discussion of these techniques is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I really do not want to know the techniques. Do you have an estimate on how much time does it take for a very skilled hacker to root the phone / or to get that file / or bypass the lock screen password?

Comment: @Zsolt: That would vary on vintage of the device and how good a PIN/passcode was. Minutes to hours is well within reason IIRC. You could ask to become a device administrator and thereby force the user to use a better passcode.

Answer (score 1):

On a non-rooted device, applications are sandboxed at the process and filesystem level.  Each app gets its own filesystem space that only it can access.  An application can choose to make a file world read/write, but by default they are not.  However, as noted in some of the comments and your original post, if a device is rooted then the attacker can access files virtually anywhere in the filesystem.  Android 5.0 mitigates this by enabling full enforcing Linux SE policies, so if a privileged system process is exploited it will be confined by SE policy.

That being said, it is a best practice to assume that as soon as your data hits the filesystem it can be read if not protected.  You can utilize the javax crypto packages to encrypt file data.  It's best to make it protected via password which is properly hashed (PBKDF2) to create a key for the file rather than hard code it in your application.  There are numerous articles on the best approach to doing this.

Note that the Android 5.0 "encrypted filesystem" is not a failsafe for this.  What the encrypted filesystem provides you with is protection of the data partition when the device is powered on.  The user provided password is used at boot time to mount the encrypted partition (just like on desktop OS encrypted volumes.)  Once it is mounted, it looks just like any other mounted filesystem.